# Difficulty finding a power series representation

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have to find a power series representation and interval of convergence for $$f(x) = \frac{x-x^2}{(1+2x)^3}$$

Noting that $\frac{1}{1+2x}=\frac{1}{1-(-2x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-2x)^n$, I start taking derivatives until I arrive at $$\frac{1}{(1+2x)^3} = \frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(2)^{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(2)^{n-1}(n+2)(n+1)x^n$$

But I'm looking for $$\frac{x-x^2}{(1+2x)^3} = (x-x^2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(2)^{n-1}(n+2)(n+1)x^n$$

This is where I'm stuck. In general, I just don't know how to deal with this sort of situation where I have to multiply a power series by multiple separate values in the function's numerator. The manipulations required on the separate sums trip me up. For example, in this case I tried

$$\left(x\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(2)^{n-1}(n+2)(n+1)x^n\right) - \left(x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(2)^{n-1}(n+2)(n+1)x^n\right)$$

Which eventually gives me

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(2)^{n-1}(n+2)(n+1)\left(x^{n+1} - x^{n+2}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(2)^{n-1}(n+2)(n+1)\left(x^n(x - x^2)\right) $$

Is this right? It really seems too complicated to me, I can't see any simple way to apply the ratio test to this so as to obtain its interval of convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Once you arrive at
$$
x\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(2)^{n-1}(n+2)(n+1)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(2)^{n-1}(n+2)(n+1)x^{n+1}
$$ you can make *a change of index*, setting $m=n+1$ thus $n=m-1$, giving
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n2^{n-1}(n+2)(n+1)x^{n+1}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m-1}2^{m-2}(m+1)mx^m
$$ then collecting the general terms in the two series.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you're almost there...

What you seem to miss here is **reindexing**.

Group the (infinite) sums you got according to $x^n$'s:

$$\sum_{n\ge0} a_nx^{n+1} + \sum_{n\ge0} b_nx^{n+2} = \sum_{k\ge 1}(a_{k-1}+b_{k-2})x^k $$
where $k=n+1$ is the new index, and $b_{-1}$ is taken as $0$.

Comment: I studied up a bit on reindexing and tried this. I ultimately arrived at $$x+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}[(-1)^{k-1}(2)^{k-2}(k+1)(k)-(-1)^{k-2}(2)^{k-3}(k)(k-1)]x^k$$, which looks similar to your final sum $$\sum_{k\geq 1}(a_{k-1} + b_{k-2})x^k$$ Is this correct? If so, would I just use the ratio test as normal to find the interval of convergence for it?

Comment: Well, yes it should be something like that.